# xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0.auto: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

When I Muti-times to plugin and pullout **USB**, the controller tips:
[xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0.auto: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command]
**Kernel 4.19.4**, CPU: **AM4379**
here is log as below:

```
[  329.415118] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0.auto: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[  329.422370] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0.auto: Host halt failed, -110
[  329.424081] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0.auto: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[  329.426485] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0.auto: HC died; cleaning up
```

what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Submit a bug to kernel bugzilla and / or Linux USB development mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

If you have got -110 status it means that there was timeout somewhere in the xhci driver. It may mean that there is some problem in the xhci driver or xhci hardware (usb host controller). If you aren't Linux kernel developer you can't do much, but that what you can do is to reload xhci driver with rmmod/insmod or via sysfs. The other way is to try to report such a bug in Linux usb mailing list and wait for some solution/bugfix.

Comment: Can confirm had a similar issue, only my keyboard additionally couldn't work. Typed using virtual keyboard, rmmod, modprobe xhci_pci to reinsert the driver. This super sucks